# Huge data download using streams from Hana db

Tags: node.js, hana

We have a table in Hana db which has data in huge volume (approx. 1 000 000 000 records/ 10GB of size). We want to download this to client's destination using streams.

**Issue:** If I am selecting all the data from table at once ,its getting break.

So need suggestions to download huge data to clients with streaming, so that I can take the data from database in streams and download to clients.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Please try to avoid using words like *crore* that are not globally understood. I tried to fix your question, hopefully it's correct now.